# Remove duplicate key from dictionary using linq in C#

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have tried below code to remove duplicate key from dictionary before adding it.

**Sample code:**

```
string conString = "Host = local;UserName = UID; Password = PWD;Host =localhost";
        var sp = conString.Split(';');
        Dictionary<string, string> keyValue = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (var k in sp)
        {
            if (k.Contains('='))
            {
                var conSP = k.Split(new char[] { '=' }, 2);
                if (keyValue.All(i =>
                 i.Key != conSP[0]))
                    keyValue.Add(conSP[0], conSP[1]);
            }
        }
```

**Sample Result**:

KeyValue[0].Key = Host, KeyValue[0].Value = local 
KeyValue[1].Key = username, KeyValue[1].Value = UID 
KeyValue[2].Key = Password, KeyValue[2].Value = PWD

But I need same result using linq. So I tried below code with linq to get output.

```
var keyValue = conString.Split(';')
                               .Where(kvp => kvp.Contains('='))
                               .Select(kvp => kvp.Split(new char[] { '=' }, 2))
                               .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp[0].Trim(),kvp => kvp[1].Trim(),StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

But in this code I got the below exception.

"An item with the same key has already been added"

Can anyone suggest me how to resolve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A dictionary only allows unique keys so you cannot have duplicates.

Comment: Why do you have to use linq?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Sedat Kapanoglu described; you shouldn't add duplicate item. You should check it before adding.
So, to remove duplicates, you can perform it like this;

```
        var keyValue = conString.Split(';')
            .Where(kvp => kvp.Contains('='))
            .Select(kvp => kvp.Split(new char[] { '=' }, 2))
            .GroupBy(kvp => kvp[0])
            .Select(kvp => kvp.FirstOrDefault())
            .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp[0].Trim(), kvp => kvp[1].Trim(), StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try this LINQ query:

```
var d = sp.Select(x => x.Split('='))
          .GroupBy(x => x[0])
          .Select(x => x.First())
          .ToDictionary(x => x[0], x=> x[1]);
```

Result:

```
[Host ,  local]
[UserName ,  UID]
[Password ,  PWD]
```

Answer (score 0):

[Connection String Builder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-string-builders) is more apropriate for parsing connection strings, but it keeps the last value:

```
new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnectionStringBuilder(
                              "Host = local;UserName = UID; Password = PWD;Host =localhost")
```

results in:

```
Key         Value
host        localhost
username    UID
password    PWD
```